# SQL to shorten long integer to 4 or 5 character number with two decimal places

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to write SQL code to convert this `00004000000000000000000000000000` to this `40.00.` And convert this `00025000000000000000000000000000` to this `250.00`  Any help?
Here is what I have so far:

```
to_number(to_char(substr(trim(to_char(nvl(pre_tax,0),'00000000000000000000000000000000')),1,8),'9999999.99'))/100 as pre_tax,
trim(to_char(substr(to_char(nvl(pre_tax,0),'00000000000000000000000000000000'),9,8),'99999999'))/100000 as pre_tax_pct,
to_number(to_char(substr(trim(to_char(nvl(roth,0),'00000000000000000000000000000000')),1,8),'9999999.99'))/100 as roth_amt,
trim(to_char(substr(to_char(nvl(roth,0),'00000000000000000000000000000000'),9,8),'99999999'))/100000 as roth_pct
```

Comment: Is the whole string supposed to represent one number? Or - given how you're currently substringing it, at least 2; and probably 3, of 8 digits each? Including non-zero elements for the 2nd/3rd parts, and how you expect those to be presented, would probably help.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SQL> WITH vals AS ( /* Test input */
  2      SELECT '00004000000000000000000000000000' AS input_value FROM dual
  3      UNION
  4      SELECT '00025000000000000000000000000000' FROM dual
  5  )
  6  select to_char(input_value / 10E25, '999G990D00') result
  7  from vals;

RESULT
-----------
      40,00
     250,00

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your query attempt, it appears you have two fixed-format 32-character strings, called `pre_tax` and `roth`; and you want to extract the first 8-character and second 8-character chunks out from each, convert them to numbers, and present them as formatted text. The first chunk is supposed to represent six significant digits before the decimal point and two after; while the second has three digits before and five after the decimal. Probably...

So you could do that with:

```
-- CTE for sample data, including a second row with more digits
with your_table (pre_tax, roth) as (
  select '00004000000000000000000000000000', '00025000000000000000000000000000' from dual
  union all
  select '12345678901234567890000000000000', null from dual
)
-- actual query
select to_char(nvl(to_number(substr(pre_tax, 1, 8)), 0) / 100, '999990D99') as pre_tax_amt,
       to_char(nvl(to_number(substr(pre_tax, 9, 8)), 0) / 100000, '990D99999') as pre_tax_pct,
       to_char(nvl(to_number(substr(roth, 1, 8)), 0) / 100, '9999990D99') as roth_amt,
       to_char(nvl(to_number(substr(roth, 9, 8)), 0) / 100000, '990D99999') as roth_pct
from your_table;

    PRE_TAX_AM PRE_TAX_PC ROTH_AMT    ROTH_PCT  
---------- ---------- ----------- ----------
     40.00    0.00000      250.00    0.00000
 123456.78  901.23456        0.00    0.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to see what your code's currently doing, but this will do what you're looking for (the last 'final_outp' column, the other columns just show how to build up to it).

```
WITH vals AS ( /* Test input */
    SELECT '00004000000000000000000000000000' AS input_value FROM dual
    UNION
    SELECT '00025000000000000000000000000000' FROM dual
)

SELECT v.input_value,

       /* Get the part of string that appears before decimal (first 6 characters) */
       SUBSTR(v.input_value,0,6) AS part_before_decimal,

       /* Get the part of string that appears after decimal (all characters after first 6) */
       SUBSTR(v.input_value,6) AS part_after_decimal,

       /* Add decimal character in between */
       SUBSTR(v.input_value,0,6) || '.' || SUBSTR(v.input_value,6) AS char_string_with_decimal, 

       /* Convert string with decimal to numeric value */
       to_number(
           SUBSTR(v.input_value,0,6) || '.' || SUBSTR(v.input_value,6),
           '999999.999999999999999999999999999'
       ) AS numeric_value,

       /* Convert numeric value back to string in desired format, and trim leading spaces */
       trim(
           to_char(
               to_number(
                   SUBSTR(v.input_value,0,6) || '.' || SUBSTR(v.input_value,6),
                   '999999.999999999999999999999999999'
               ),
               '999999.99'
           )
       ) AS final_outp 
FROM vals v
```